# Passar array para um método php

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho um formulário onde um dos campos é file multiple, ou seja, o usuário pode enviar mais de uma foto para o banco de dados, porém preciso passar as fotos, caso seja mais de uma, para o método de cadastro. Veja abaixo:

```
$nomeProduto = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"NomeProduto");
$valorProduto = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"ValorProduto");
......
$fotos = $_FILES["FotoProduto"]["name"];

$metodos->cadastrarProdutos($nomeProduto,$valorProduto,....,$fotos);
```

O método:

```
public function cadastrarProdutos($nomeProduto,$valorProduto,....,$fotos){
   // Aqui eu pegar todas as fotos que foram enviadas
}
```

Como eu faria para passar essas fotos para método? Pensei em usar o **foreach()** e o **implode(",",$fotos);** e dentro do método resgatar com o **explode(",",$fotos);**. Teria alguma outra solução?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As vezes é mais simples do que a gente pensa. Em vez de você já passar como parâmetro o `$_FILES["FotoProduto"]["name"]`, passe simplesmente o `$_FILES["FotoProduto"]` e no [*foreach*](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php) você pode usar o `["name"]` como quiser. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
foreach($_FILES["FotoProduto"] as $file) {
  if($file['size'])
    echo $file['name']."\n";
}
```

Então no seu método você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$fotos = $_FILES["FotoProduto"];

public function cadastrarProdutos($nomeProduto,$valorProduto,....,$fotos){
   foreach($fotos as $file) {
      if($file['size'])
        echo $file['name']."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Ack Lay.